# models/research/gan/pix2pix : bazel-bin error no such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm having issue with `launch_script.sh` for pix2pix sample in `models/research/gan/pix2pix`

After looking into the script, it stuck at these lines

```
bazel build "${git_repo}/research/slim:download_and_convert_imagenet"
"./bazel-bin/download_and_convert_imagenet" ${DATASET_DIR}
```

I've looked up previous questions (both here and Issues in Tensorflow's `models` repo, and many said that it's because bazel configurations, mismatching between where bazel looks and where bazel generates. But after looking up all directories created by bazel, there's no directories of what I've been missing

I'm doing this on my Azure VM on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. This is my first time working with bazel. So sorry for lack of knowledge in bazel. I'd be very thankful if someone can help solve this problem

Comment: What platform are you building on? Did you run ./configure.sh? Can you share the error log?

Comment: @mhlopko I've added my platform specification. Also, what do you mean by ./configure.sh? And where I can found this

Comment: I'm sorry, it's only ./configure, without .sh. It's the script that set's up tensorflow configuration.